# Java animation only showing last frame

Tags: java, animation, frame

So when my player walks, the last frame of the animation is only being desplayed. playerW[11] is the last frame that is displayed. If i were to remove that and leave playerW[10], that element ends up being only dislpayed. Not sure what is screwed up here. I checked around but didnt find much relevence.

```
public class Animation {

private int speed;
private int frames;


private int index = 0;
private int count = 0;

private BufferedImage[] images;
private BufferedImage currentImg;


public Animation(int speed, BufferedImage... args){
    this.speed = speed;
    images = new BufferedImage[args.length];

    for(int i = 0; i <args.length; i++){
        images[i] = args[i];
    }

    frames = args.length;
}



public void runAnimation(){
    index++;
    if(index > speed){
        index = 0;
        nextFrame();
    }
}


private void nextFrame(){
    for(int i = 0; i < frames; i++){
        if (count == i){
            currentImg = images[i];
        }

        count++;

        if(count> frames){
            count =0;
        }
    }
}


public void drawAnimation(Graphics g, int x, int y){
    g.drawImage(currentImg, x, y, null);
}


}

public class Player {

private BufferedImage player;  //idle

private BufferedImage[] playerW = new BufferedImage[12];   //walking

private Animation playerWalking;

public Player(double x, double y, Game game){

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    SpriteSheet ss = new SpriteSheet(game.getSpriteSheet());




    //idle///////////////////////////
    player = ss.grabImage(1,1,66,94);  
    /////////////////////////////////







    //walking//////////////////////////////
    playerW[0] = ss.grabImage(1,2,66,100);
    playerW[1] = ss.grabImage(2,3,66,100);
    playerW[2] = ss.grabImage(3,2,64,100);
    playerW[3] = ss.grabImage(4,2,60,100);
    playerW[4] = ss.grabImage(5,2,60,100);
    playerW[5] = ss.grabImage(6,2,64,100);
    playerW[6] = ss.grabImage(7,2,64,100);
    playerW[7] = ss.grabImage(8,2,64,100);
    playerW[8] = ss.grabImage(9,2,64,100);
    playerW[9] = ss.grabImage(10,2,64,100);
    playerW[10] = ss.grabImage(11,2,64,100);
    playerW[11] = ss.grabImage(12,2,64,100);
    ////////////////////////////////////////

    playerWalking = new Animation(6, playerW[0], playerW[1], playerW[2] , playerW[3], playerW[4], playerW[5], playerW[6], playerW[7], playerW[8] , playerW[9] , playerW[10] , playerW[11]);
}

public void tick(){

    playerWalking.runAnimation();

    x+=velX;
    y+=velY;

    if(x<=0){
        x = 0;
    }

    if(x>=625 - 35){
        x = 625 - 35;
    }

    if(y <= 80){
        y = 80;
    }

    if(y >= 280 - 100){
        y = 280-100;
    }



}


public void render(Graphics g){


    if(velX != 0){
        playerWalking.drawAnimation(g,(int)x, (int)y);
    }
    else{  //idle
        g.drawImage(player, (int)x,(int)y,null);    
    }
```

Comment: It needs to update the graphics from another thread, you can use SwingWorker to do it.

Comment: How is `tick` called? How is `render` called? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses. You might like to take a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: take another look at your nextFrame method, currently your nextFrame methods gets the current frame instead of next frame you should change it too: 

private void nextFrame(){
    for(int i = 0; i < frames-1; i++){
        if (count == i){
            currentImg = images[i+1];
        }

        count++;

        if(count> frames){
            count =0;
        }
    }
}

Comment: i made an adjustment in the next frame method. I change the if statement to if(count==0){ currentImg = images[i]; } and it seemed to fix it. Thanks everyone for replying and Nima for making me realize the problem was with that method :)